# Pika single queue with multiple consumers

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, pika

Python program running a single queue with multiple consumers

I'm looking for the when the queue receives the multiple messages( ex: 10 messages),

Is there any way that multiple consumers(ex: 5 consumers) share the message load from the queue something like each consumer consume 2 messages from the Queue?

Please suggest me any alternate ways to reduce the load on the queue by creating multiple consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to "play" with the [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html),
This is what will make sure that a single consumer doesn't greedily take all the messages in the queue, then treats them one by one (a quite common situation).

From the documentation:

```
Channel channel = ...;
Consumer consumer = ...;
channel.basicQos(2); // Per consumer limit
channel.basicConsume("my-queue", false, consumer);
```

This would mean the consumer will only be allowed to have 2 *unacknowledged* messages at any given time.

Till he acknowledges one of the messages (which it should do once he's done processing it), he'll be able to pick more.

Comment: Used the consumer prefetch, its fetching the 2 unacknowledged messages.

Here issue is only one consumer is picking all the messages when multiple consumers are available for single queue.

Comment: So you have messages left in the queue, and only a single process consuming, while the others are doing nothing?

Comment: Unless you have started the consumers from the same piece of code *and* they share a channel *and* a per channel prefetch limit has been set, I do now know how you can come to that situation.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, by changing the prefetch count able to work. Need some help on how to know the queue Threshold or queue getting backed up in pika when it's getting huge number of messages.

Comment: @mka can you clarify what kind of information you'd like regarding threshold? Not sure what you mean by queue getting backed up. If you mean it fills up are we talking issues with rabbitmq stability, or more on how to configure limits and what rabbitmq should do when reaching said limits?

Comment: Using Pika I'm creating Queue with a consumer consume queue messages, when huge no. of messages published to queue(Ex: 2000), how to know pressure or threshold on the queue before consumption, so that I can create another consumer for the same queue to reduce pressure and two consumers for single queue consume messages.

Comment: Depends on how you picture this, but if we're talking some kind of orchestration, I'd personnaly be using the [http api](https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html#queue-metrics) to get the number of messages in the queue as well as the current delivery rate, to trigger the start of another consumer